# ¿Como conecto con axios a la API de Woocommerce o Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, woocommerce

estoy con vuejs y axios intentando conectar a la api de woocommerce, pero no encuentro la forma de enviar correctamente mis credenciales (las claves), o no se si tengo que especificar el método de conexión... No se como indicarlo en axios.

Esta es la parte donde intento conectar:

```
getPosts: function() {
  var app = this
  axios.get('http://192.168.0.163/development/wp-json/wc/v2/products/', {
          headers: {
              "consumerKey": "ck_xxxxxx",
              "consumerSecret": "cs_xxxxxxx"
            }
        })
    .then(function (response) {
      app.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

Recibo un 401, no tengo permisos. Entonces, en postman he intentado conectar, especificando el método de conexión 0Auth 1.0 y si funciona, que el problema está en el código js de axios.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando las cabeceras incorrectas. La especificación OAuth dice que necesita una concatenación de los siguientes datos en la cabecera `Authorization`:

> - `oauth_consumer_key`: identifica al cliente que hace la petición.
> - `oauth_nonce`: token único que es generado para cada petición.
> - `oauth_signature`: hash generado a partir del resto de cabeceras mediante un algoritmo específico.
> - `oauth_signature_method`: tipo de hash, por ejemplo [`HMAC-SHA1`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).
> - `oauth_timestamp`: timestamp de la fecha al instante de ser creada la petición.
> - `oauth_token`: token de la aplicación.
> - `oauth_version`: versión del protocolo.

Todos estos datos deben ir separados por espacios como un solo string para la cabecera `Authorization` como ya se mencionó. Lo más razonable que puedes hacer es usar una librería que haga la mayoría de procesamiento y solo te centres en enviar tu petición; por ejemplo, la librería [OAuth 1.0a](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) te abstrae de estos procesos. Funciona en ambos lados.

**Generando la cabecera**

Primero necesitas las siguientes dependencias:

- [Google CryptoJS](https://github.com/sytelus/CryptoJS/tree/master/rollups). Necesitarás importas los ficheros de los algoritmos que necesitarás y también el codificador base64. Por ejemplo:

  ```
    <script src="/libs/cryptojs/hmac-sha1.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/cryptijs/hmac-sha256"></script>
  ```
- [OAuth 1.0a](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a) obviamente.

  ```
    <script src="/libs/oauth-1.0.js"></script>
  ```

Luego construyes la cabecera:

```
const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        key: '<clave>',
        secret: '<secreto>'
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1', // algoritmo
    hash_function: function(base_string, key) {
        return crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(base_string).digest('base64');
    }
});
```

Esta librería te permite convertir dicha instancia a la cabecera ya formateada o como datos para petición. Te interesa como cabecera, por lo que debes usar el método `toHeader(<datos_petición>, <token>)`:

```
// datos de la petición
const requestSettings = {
  url: '<url>',
  method: 'GET',
};

// token de acceso
const token = {
  key: '<api key>',
  secret: '<secreto'>,
};

axios
  .get(requestSettings.url, {
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize(requestSettings, token))
  })
  .then((response) => {
     // manejar respuesta
  });
```

---

Te recomiendo que vayas migrando a OAuth 2.0, cuyo mecanismo de autenticación es tremendamente más sencillo que su predecesor.

**Links de interés**

- [OAuth 2.0 en Wordpress](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/).
- [Diferencias entre OAuth 1.0 y OAuth 2.0](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/differences-between-oauth-1-2).
- [OAuth 2.0 y Bearer tokens](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/differences-between-oauth-1-2/bearer-tokens/).

**Referencias**

- [RFC 5849 - Especificación del protocolo OAuth 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).
- [OAuth 1.0 Revisión a](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/).
- [Autorización de peticiones](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests)